# Is it 需要は多い or 需要は高い

Tags: grammar

需要 {じゅよう｝　means demand, like the economic demand.

But how do you say the demand is high, with 高い or 多い ?

Answer (score 2):

Both 多い and 高い are widely used, and you can use them interchangeably. Here are hit results from [BCCWJ](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/):

- 需要が多い / 需要の多い / 需要は多い: 35 results
- 需要が高い / 需要の高い / 需要は高い: 28 results

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of like in English: when people talk about demand, there isn't any single set phrase.

What expression to use depends on the sense you want to impart.  Is demand "strong"?  Is there "a lot" of demand?  Is demand "high"?  Is demand "vigorous"?  Is demand "active"?  Is demand "healthy"?

Informally poking around the web, I found the following collocations, among many other possibilities.  Listed in order of most to least:

- ["需要が多い"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E3%81%8C%E5%A4%9A%E3%81%84%22) - 13.4M
- ["需要が高い"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E3%81%8C%E9%AB%98%E3%81%84%22) - 11.7M
- ["需要が高まって"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E3%81%8C%E9%AB%98%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%22) - 2.2M
- ["需要が盛ん"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E3%81%8C%E7%9B%9B%E3%82%93%22) - 394K
- ["需要が旺盛"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E3%81%8C%E6%97%BA%E7%9B%9B%22) - 108K
- ["需要が盛り上がって"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E3%81%8C%E7%9B%9B%E3%82%8A%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%22) - 85.6K
- ["需要が豊富](https://www.google.com/search?ei=mNJ-W_QBsvX0A4WQjaAI&q=%22%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E3%81%8C%E8%B1%8A%E5%AF%8C%22&oq=%22%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E3%81%8C%E8%B1%8A%E5%AF%8C%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...31451.47472.0.48927.8.8.0.0.0.0.90.425.8.8.0....0...1.1j4.64.psy-ab..0.5.284...0i7i30k1j0i4i37k1j0i7i4i30k1.0.7fJzHJiLE6g) - 3,950
- ["需要が強い"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E3%81%8C%E5%BC%B7%E3%81%84%22) - 3,190
- ["需要が活発"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E3%81%8C%E6%B4%BB%E7%99%BA%22) - 1,260
- ["需要が活況"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E3%81%8C%E6%B4%BB%E6%B3%81%22) - 282
- ["需要が健全"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E3%81%8C%E5%81%A5%E5%85%A8%22) - 8

Note that including different grammatical inflections (such as 盛り上がった, 高く, that kind of thing) might change this result distribution somewhat.